# Next js session version 4 with middleware client side

Tags: javascript, session, next.js

I'm using next js session v4.0.4 client side with middleware and i wanna know how to store user credential in the session in login page
my middleware.js :

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import session from 'next-session'

export async function middleware(req, res) {
  await session()(req, res)
  return NextResponse.next()
}
```

my session.js

```
import nextSession from 'next-session'


export const getSession = nextSession()
function withSession(handler) {
  return async function handlerWithSession(req, res) {
    await getSession(req, res)
    return handler(req, res)
  }
}

function applySessionOptions(req, res) {
  return getSession(req, res)
}

function withSessionOptions(handler) {
  return withSession(handler)
}

export { applySessionOptions as applySession }
export { withSessionOptions as withSession }
```

My  login service

```
import { withSession} from './session'
const handler = async (req, res) => {
 try {
        req.session.logged = true,
        req.session.commit();
  
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
export default withSession(handler)
```

When i do console.log(req.session) in my login page i find the logged value
but when i try to access from another service the req.session i don't find the logged value any help please